# Can the sensitivity level be set for a message in Outlook 360 via the JavaScript API for Office?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

How can I set the sensitivity level (normal, confidential, etc) for an Outlook message via the JavaScript API for Office?

I have searched the reference docs and this functionality does not appear to be exposed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook?view=office-js

Answer (score 2):

Currently we don't have any outlook add-in JS APIs for setting the Sensitivity of an item. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have submitted my request.  The link is [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/37471114-ability-to-set-sensitivity-level-of-an-email-messa) in case others would like to vote for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering if there have been any updates to this topic? It looks like you will soon be able to [set the sensitivity on an appointment item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/outlook/office.sensitivity?view=outlook-js-preview) . Is it still not possible to set it on a mail item without REST or EWS?

Also the user voice link leads me to a page that says "This site is not currently active"

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API in Office JS for setting the Sensitivity of an item.

You can use either [REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api) or [EWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services) to set the sensitivity of the item. Office JS has the capability to provide you with tokens (using [getCallbackTokenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox#getcallbacktokenasyncoptions-callback) API) to interact with Exchange.

This [repository](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo/tree/master/RestCaller) is a basic example explaining how to make REST calls from a web add-ins .